# Do I need odd and even rolls for half drop wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper

I am about to order half drop wallpaper for the first time so I'm trying to estimate the correct number of rolls.

I understand the half-drop wallpaper is supplied in odd and even rolls, so that you can "start from the beginning" of every roll and odd rolls will line up with even ones.

Here's the thing - because the height of wall that I am papering is slightly less than 2.5 times the pattern repeat, is it not the case that I can just cut the next drop from the same (odd) roll? i.e. from the same "odd" roll, I would be cutting the first two drops of 2.5 repeats, resulting in 5 repeats used for the first two drops. Repeating that would mean that I would want all odd rolls.

If I used an even roll for the second drop, and returned to the odd roll for the third drop, then I would have over half a pattern length wastage (to begin the third roll at the beginning of the third repeat, then between repeats 2.5 and 3, the roll is wasted.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: hmm I think I get it now.... the rolls are all supplied the same. Using odd and even rolls is just a trick to help you with cutting the lengths. The amount of waste will be the same whether you cut from alternate rolls or not.

Comment: Have you asked the vendor from whom you're about to order this? I'd imagine they could probably explain it to a layman...